# Условие на длину получаемого обьекта из формы

Tags: ajax, django

Практикуюсь в Django+Ajax. Использую Ajax с jQuery.
Есть форма, заполняю поле, жму кнопку - проверяется соответствие условию.
Проблема: Выдает один и тот же результат в независимости от кол-ва символов. Ошибка в синтаксисе или ajax вообще не работает у меня?

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#done").click(function() {
        $.get("/create_test/", function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="create"></input>

    <br><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="done" value="check">
</form>



</body>
```

view:

```
def create(request):
return render_to_response('create.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def create_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        text = request.POST.get('create', '')
        if len(text) <= 20:
            message = "AJAX: подходит!"
            return HttpResponse(message)
        else:
            message = "AJAX: не подходит!"
            return HttpResponse(message)
    else:
        message = "это не AJAX =("
        return HttpResponse(message)
```

Выводит постоянно "AJAX: подходит!"
получил len(text) равную 0. Я так понимаю сам запрос не выполняется, т.е. данные из строки не передаются и соответственно длина строки равно нулю. Значит ошибка в скрипте, подскажите что нужно дописать?

Comment: получил len(text) равную 0. Я так понимаю сам запрос не выполняется, т.е. данные из строки не передаются и соответственно длина строки равно нулю. Значит ошибка в скрипте, подскажите что нужно дописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте отправить запрос ajax таким образом:

```
$("#done").click(function() {
    Data = $.("create").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/create_test/",
        method: 'POST',
        data: { 'text': Data },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Записать данные не удалось');
        },
    });
});
```

Тогда получать реквест в виде json на сервере можно так:

```
from json import loads
text = loads(request.POST['text'])
```

Или можно получить реквест так:

```
text = request.POST['text']
```

Смотря какая структура данных у вас будет передаваться в итоге.